# Authenticate_Execute event override in Kentico CMS v8.2

Tags: c#, kentico

I need to convert a Kentico 7 web application to Kentico 8.0.21. The old code has a CMSModuleLoader file in the App_Code folder which has code for Authenticate_Execute event. 
The init event suggested by kentico does not get fired

```
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
private class AuthenticationHandler : CMSLoaderAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called automatically when the application starts
    /// </summary>
    public override void Init()
    {
        // Assigns a handler to the SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute event
        // This event occurs when users attempt to log in on the website
        SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute += OnAuthentication;
    }
    private void OnAuthentication(object sender, AuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.User != null) //the authenticate was successful
        {
            try
            {
                var accountFacade = WebContainer.Instance.Container.GetInstance<IAccountFacade>();
                accountFacade.ReconcileOnLogin(args.UserName);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                var ex = new Exception("IAccountFacade.ReconcileOnLogin method throw an error communicating with dynamics, the issue is not resolvable from Kentico thus regardless of the permission level of the current user, the exception will be bubbled up and the user will be shown error details or the custom error page.", e);
                logger.Fatal(x => x("The current exception is caused by dynamics/data problems and the user will not be allowed to login. A system admin with access to dynamics is required to resolve the problem.", e));
                throw ex;
            }
            //ResetPasswordAttempts(args.User);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Attribute class that ensures the loading of custom handlers
/// </summary>
private class CustomSecurityEventsAttribute : CMS.Base.CMSLoaderAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called automatically when the application starts
    /// </summary>
    public override void Init()
    {
        SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute += new     EventHandler<AuthenticationEventArgs>(Authenticate_Execute);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called on every kentico authenticate attempt
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
```

Comment: Do you have those attributes listed above the CMSModuleLoader as shown in Rocky's response?[AuthenticationHandler]

Answer (score 4):

All authentication-related events were moved to `CMS.Membership.SecurityEvents` in Kentico 8.0. The usage is as follows:

```
using System.Data;

using CMS.Base;
using CMS.Membership;
using CMS.DataEngine;

[AuthenticationHandler]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom attribute class.
    /// </summary>
    private class AuthenticationHandler : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Called automatically when the application starts
        /// </summary>
        public override void Init()
        {
            // Assigns a handler to the SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute event
            // This event occurs when users attempt to log in on the website
            SecurityEvents.Authenticate.Execute += OnAuthentication;
        }
    }
}
```

For more info refer to the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Handling+custom+external+authentication).